# How to disable Google Chrome auto update for MAC OS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, auto-update

Does anyone know how to disable Google Chrome auto-update for MAC OS?

I tried:

1. Renaming the `GoogleSoftwareUpdate` folder
2. Change Google Chrome auto-update URL
3. Command `defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0` in terminal

It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Related: [superuser: How to remove Google Software Update from Mac OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/730736/how-to-remove-google-software-update-from-mac-osx)

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this?

Comment: @ATOMP first reason that comes to mind is testing UX/UI on older versions. The discussion on wether clients should offer support for their UI for older browser versions, leave it to chance, or block the older browsers altogether is a completely different topic.

Comment: `why would anyone want to do this?` -- Well, if you're working with an older MacBook and don't have the financial means to upgrade to the newer, more expensive Mac models, it's preferable to stick with your existing device and use an outdated version of the Chrome browser. The latest Chrome updates are incompatible with older Macs.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Method that helped me:

1. To empty these directories:

```
/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/
~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/
```

2. Then change the permissions on these folders named 'GoogleSoftwareUpdate' so that there's no owner and no read/write/execute permissions.

In terminal:

```
cd /Library/Google/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate
sudo chmod 000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate
cd ~/Library/Google/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate
sudo chmod 000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate
```

3. Then do the same for the folder Google one level up.

```
cd /Library/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup Google
sudo chmod 000 Google
cd ~/Library/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup Google
sudo chmod 000 Google
```

I did this after installing the Chrome version I need. 
Now when I'll check 'About Google Chrome' I'll see  the error "Update failed (error: 10)"

Comment: I thank myself for posting this answer then. The laptop had to be changed and the instructions came in handy again :-)

Comment: Can you still perform manual updates after performing this procedure? and would the be using in-app update feature or would you need to manually download and install newer versions?

Comment: To re-enable it to be able to update again, you can `rm -rf ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate` and `rm -rf /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate` if it exists and re-launch Chrome. The directory will be re-created as writable. No profile info will be lost.

Comment: After trying many methods, only this works. Thanks.

Comment: it does not work. macOS version: Big Sur 11.7.10 (20G1427), chrome browser version:120.0.6099.109

Answer (score 2):

After struggling a lot, found an easy solution for **Mac**. Hope this will help others.

1. Leave it to upgrade.
2. Then go to application, right click on chrome app and open package contents.
3. Navigate further as `/Applications/Google Chrome old.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions`
4. You will find a `current` folder. **Delete this :)**
5. Restart chrome and enjoy..

Answer (score 1):

After deleted current folder. If you launch chrome again, chrome still would upgrade automatically.

`/Applications/Google Chrome old.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/current`

Would generate the folder again.

/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate folder's permission and the owner would be recovered

If you want to use the specific version of chrome for selenium chrome webdriver, you could download chromium for it.

Ref.
https://chromium.woolyss.com/
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with v86+ versions of chrome. Uninstall v86 first and do the following steps:

Download Chrome v85 from here :

> `https://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac/download/2460182`

To Stop Auto Updates (Alternate method Oct 24, 2020 - Method 1)

```
/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/
~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/
```

Then change the permissions on these folders named '`GoogleSoftwareUpdate`' so that there's no owner and no read/write/execute permissions.

```
cd /Library/Google/

sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate

sudo chmod 000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate

cd ~/Library/Google/

sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate

sudo chmod 000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate


cd /Library/

sudo chown nobody:nogroup Google

sudo chmod 000 Google

cd ~/Library/

sudo chown nobody:nogroup Google

sudo chmod 000 Google
```

To Stop Auto Updates (Alternate method Oct 24, 2020 - Method 1)

> https://osxdaily.com/2012/04/06/disable-google-chrome-automatic-software-update/

This works to stop Google Chrome from updating itself automatically in Mac OS X:

1. Launch the Terminal,
   Go to :    **cd /Applications/Utilities/**
2. Enter the following defaults write command and hit return:

> `defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0`

3. Exit out of Terminal and restart Google Chrome

Comment: related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/199151