# SyntaxError: not a PNG file

Tags: python, png

For the longest time, I've been using

```
dfi.export(df1, "test.png")
```

to export a dataframe styler (df1) with type pandas.io.formats.style.Styler into a .png.

Today I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3369 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Input In [48] in <cell line: 1>
    dfi.export(df1, "ice_cotton_" + str(dashboard_date).split(" ")[0])

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataframe_image\_pandas_accessor.py:48 in export
    return _export(

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataframe_image\_pandas_accessor.py:117 in _export
    img_str = converter(html)

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataframe_image\_screenshot.py:188 in run
    img = self.take_screenshot()

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataframe_image\_screenshot.py:140 in take_screenshot
    img = mimage.imread(buffer)

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py:1560 in imread
    with img_open(fname) as image:

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py:112 in __init__
    self._open()

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py:676 in _open
    raise SyntaxError("not a PNG file")

  File <string>
SyntaxError: not a PNG file
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: And what did you change today? [mre]

Comment: Nothing! I think it is to do with the new version dataframe-image 0.1.5 just released. https://pypi.org/project/dataframe-image/

Comment: So you _did_ install that new version?

Comment: Yes. But I still get the same error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75135530/error-exporting-styled-dataframes-to-image <-- This guy seems to be ok though.

Comment: If you don't absolutely need that new version revert to the old one?

Comment: I had tried that too. And went to install the older version, but still got the same error. So I guess I need to go a couple of versions back..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error exporting styled dataframes to image, "SyntaxError: not a PNG file" using dataframe\_image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75135530/error-exporting-styled-dataframes-to-image-syntaxerror-not-a-png-file-using)

Comment: @haikal are you sure you have upgraded dataframe_image to 0.1.5 for the code you're running? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75135530/error-exporting-styled-dataframes-to-image-syntaxerror-not-a-png-file-using/75162992#75162992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a set of possible solutions and only the last one worked for me:

1. a previous version of matplotlib, e.g. 3.4.3
2. use a backend, e.g. ‘mpl.use('ps')’
3. previous versions of dataframe-image (tested 0.1.3, 0.1.2 and 0.1.0)
4. table_conversion, e.g. dfi.export(table, table_conversion='firefox'): this gives no error but formatting is lost
5. previous version of Chrome (i.e. January 27; 109.0.5414.119): this works!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372124/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update-for-mac-os on how to prevent update of Chrome

Comment: This would even be better; just use the latest Chrome with: 
matplotlib==3.7.1, dataframe-image==0.1.10 (pip install)